# sql avg usage causing illegal ordering of resultset

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my SQL

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(scl_reviews.locid),avg(scl_reviews.rating)
 AS average,scl_locations.name,scl_locations.phone,scl_locations.address,
 scl_location.city,scl_locations.state,scl_locations.zip 
 FROM scl_reviews 
 LEFT JOIN scl_locations ON scl_locations.locid = scl_reviews.locid 
 GROUP BY scl_reviews.locid ORDER BY average DESC LIMIT 100
```

What this means is that it will grab `locations` with the `highest rating` and sort them by the average.

The problem is that the records with an average of 5 seem to query their positions differently. **Sometimes my record with an id of 3115 is position 1 and sometimes its position 3.**

Not quite sure whats going on,. I assume it has to do with my query.

Comment: Do you mean that on different runs of your query several rows with **equal** average are ordered differently?

Comment: try `ORDER BY average DESC, scl_reviews.locid ASC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ORDER BY average DESC` leaves undetermined how the order will be when there are equal values. So just list a unique column in the sort order. You might like the column number short-cut:

```
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a secondary order. This kicks in when your first order has equal values.
Check the new order by clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(scl_reviews.locid),avg(scl_reviews.rating)
 AS average,scl_locations.name,scl_locations.phone,scl_locations.address,
 scl_location.city,scl_locations.state,scl_locations.zip 
 FROM scl_reviews 
 LEFT JOIN scl_locations ON scl_locations.locid = scl_reviews.locid 
 GROUP BY scl_reviews.locid 
 ORDER BY average DESC, scl_reviews.locid DESC LIMIT 100
```